# Message box in Asp.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

How to display a 1056 character message in message box in asp.NET C#.

```
 Response.Write("<script>alert(' " + a + " ')</script>");
```

The above code just accepts 54 characters only.I need some other way to display the error messages for a whole page.

Comment: That would be rather annoying, dont you think?  Why not present it on a nice scrollable formatted page?

Answer (score 4):

I would use jQuery instead. It's a lot more friendly to the user than an alert and more flexible. There's a modal version if you need that as well.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) component from Ajax control toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the max limit of javascript alerts but it is certainly more than 54 chars. You may need to insert line breaks (\n) to force the text over several lines. As others have mentioned though I would also look at alternatives to displaying this in the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery UI dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  It allows you to write things like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                height: 460,
                width: 800,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Where dialog is the id of a div tag that holds the content you want to display as a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your codebehind.

```
String csname1 = "PopupScript";

            String cstext1 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
            "alert('ssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssdssssd');</" + "script>";
            RegisterStartupScript(csname1, cstext1);
```